# Comparisons between numbers

Tags: c++, numbers

Let's say I have a file with this content:

```
6 
8 
9 
12 
15
20
```

I am comparing the first number with the others then the 2nd number with all the numbers below it etc.

For each comparison, I am looking if the two numbers are separated by less than 10 for example. Then I print all the numbers that respect this condition.

At this point I should have something like this:

```
6 8
6 9
6 12 
6 15
8 9
8 12
8 15
9 12
9 15
12 15
12 20
15 20
```

But at the end, what I want is to take the minimum and the maximum values respecting the condition and to delete the rest. So I should have:

6 15

because these two numbers are the minimum and maximum values of the list respecting the condition (different by less than 10).

And then in the list only 20 is remaining. 6,8,9,12 and 15 are deleted from the list.
I tried to do something like that but it doesn't look good:

```
  for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
       {
           for(int j=i+1;j<6;j++)
           {

               if((std::abs(number[j]-number[i])<=10))
               {
                   if(number[j]<=number[j+1])
                   {
                       number[j]=number[j+1];
                   }

               }
           }
       }
```

Also, the list could contain like 10.000 values in total.

Any idea how to do it right ?

Comment: not clear why `6 15` is the soltution and not eg `12 20`. The maximum is `20` not `15`

Comment: @user463035818 The difference between `12 20` is `8` which is less than the difference between `6 15`

Comment: @GauravSehgal you might be right, but I dont see how you read that from the question. 6 and 15 are not the " the minimum and maximum values of the list" as stated by OP

Comment: @user463035818 My interpretation might be wrong. This is the right time for OP to clarify this.

Comment: @user463035818 I think the OP mean, first we obtain the comparisons that respect the condition. Then, we take the minimum and the maximum values from those of respecting the condition.

Comment: @LoveCoding 12 is not the maxium

Comment: @user463035818 `6` is the minimum and `15` is the maximum. As you can see the difference between these two combinations is higher than the rest of other valid combinations.

Comment: @LoveCoding how is 15 the max when there is also a 20 in the list?

Comment: @LoveCoding is right. What I mean is to take the minimum value of the list which is 6 here and then get the highest number respecting the condition which is 15.
12 and 20 respect the condition but 12 isn't the minimum.
15 isn't the maximum but it is the highest number respecting the condition with 6.
Sorry If i wasn't clear.

Comment: Just to clarify one other thing. Why all others are going to be deleted, except 20?

Comment: Actually, the final aim of this code is to merge the numbers in the range value (10). So in this example, all the values between 6 and 15 will be 'merged' thus becoming invisible. Then I'll compute the mean value between 6 and 15 and put it in another list.
The values that didn't respect the condition are left. So in this case, 20.

Comment: @inourss I provided an answer, and let me know if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about maintaining the best possible answer as you progress.

```
int ans_a,ans_b,maxDiffSoFar = 0;
//...

int tempDiff = std::abs(number[j]-number[i]);
if(tempDiff <= 10 && tempDiff > maxDiffSoFar)
{
     maxDifSoFar = tempDiff;
     ans_a = number[i];
     ans_b = number[j];
}
```

EDIT:
After clarification,

```
int ans_a=INT_MAX,ans_b;
//...

int tempDiff = std::abs(number[j]-number[i]);
if(tempDiff <= 10 && (ans_a > number[i] || (ans_a == number[i] && ans_b < number[j]) ))
{
     ans_a = number[i];
     ans_b = number[j];
}
```

Comment: This would work until we have the following:

6 
8 
9 
12 
15
20
22
It will give as output (12 22) instead of (6 15) and (20 22)

Comment: @inourss Check the EDIT.

Comment: This gives now (6 8) as a result.

Comment: @inourss One last try.

Comment: This is better but it still ignores the (20 22) part. Is there a way to do something like:
Ok you found (6 15) now do the same for the remaining values which should give (20 22) next ?

Answer (score 0):

May be the following code will help you to solve the problem. I hope I understand your question properly, here you go.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {6, 8, 9, 12, 15, 20, 22, 45, 99, 205};
    std::cout << "All possible combinations:" << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)) - 1; i++)
        for( int j = i + 1; j < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)); j++)
            std::cout << arr[i] << " " << arr[j] << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "Combinations respecting the condition:" << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)) - 1; i++)
        for( int j = i + 1; j < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)); j++)
            if(std::abs( arr[i] - arr[j]) < 10)
                std::cout << arr[i] << " " << arr[j] << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "Combination of mimum and maximum value respecting the condition:" << std::endl;
    int max_difference = 0, max_index = 0, min_index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)) - 1; i++)
        for( int j = i + 1; j < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)); j++)
            if( (std::abs( arr[i] - arr[j]) > max_difference) && (std::abs( arr[i] - arr[j]) < 10) )
            {
                max_difference = std::abs( arr[i] - arr[j]);
                if(arr[i] > arr[j])
                {
                    max_index = i;
                    min_index = j;
                }
                else
                {
                    max_index = j;
                    min_index = i;
                }
            }
    std::cout << arr[min_index] << " " << arr[max_index] << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "The last combinations respect the condition, but beyond the minimu and maximum range:" << std::endl;
    for(int i = max_index + 1; i < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)) - 1; i++)
        for( int j = i + 1; j < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)); j++)
            if( std::abs( arr[i] - arr[j]) < 10 )
                std::cout << arr[i] << " " << arr[j] << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "Values never satisy the condition and beyond the minimu and maximum range:" << std::endl;
    for(int i = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)) - 1; i > max_index + 1; i--)
        for( int j = i - 2; j > max_index; j--)
            if( std::abs( arr[j] - arr[i]) >= 10 )
            {
                std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
                break;
            }
    return 0;
}
```

Actually the answer you are looking for is the last loop statement. All the others above are just to make sure that if I understand your question properly. Here is the short answer you are looking for:

```
    int max_difference = 0, max_index = 0, min_index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)) - 1; i++)
        for( int j = i + 1; j < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)); j++)
            if( (std::abs( arr[i] - arr[j]) > max_difference) && (std::abs( arr[i] - arr[j]) < 10) )
            {
                max_difference = std::abs( arr[i] - arr[j]);
                if(arr[i] > arr[j])
                {
                    max_index = i;
                    min_index = j;
                }
                else
                {
                    max_index = j;
                    min_index = i;
                }
            }
    std::cout << arr[min_index] << " " << arr[max_index] << std::endl;
```

**EDIT after you clarify** 
The solution provided here is assuming that the numbers are in ascending order. Here is your solution, but the numbers not respecting the condition are displayed in descending order:

```
std::cout << std::endl << "The last combinations respect the condition, but beyond the minimu and maximum range:" << std::endl;
for(int i = max_index + 1; i < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)) - 1; i++)
    for( int j = i + 1; j < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)); j++)
        if( std::abs( arr[i] - arr[j]) < 10 )
            std::cout << arr[i] << " " << arr[j] << std::endl;

std::cout << std::endl << "Values never satisy the condition and beyond the minimu and maximum range:" << std::endl;
for(int i = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)) - 1; i > max_index + 1; i--)
    for( int j = i - 2; j > max_index; j--)
        if( std::abs( arr[j] - arr[i]) >= 10 )
        {
            std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
            break;
        }
```

The entire code is provided above. Just look at it. Remember, I added `45, 99, and 250`. But when they display, they will be displayed like: `250, 99, 45`. That would be simple you have to re-arrange it by yourself. I hope it help.

Regards.

Comment: This works perfectly ! Is there a way to print the remaining number i.e. 20 in this case ?

Comment: @inourss That is the question I really didn't understand. I asked you about it yesterday on the comments below your question, but you didn't replied. What are/is the logic behind deleting all other numbers, except `20`? In that case, we can be able to help you.

Comment: I answered just before your last comment but basically:

What I want to do is to merge numbers in the range value (10). So in this example, all the values between 6 and 15 will be 'merged' thus becoming invisible (not litteraly deleted). The values that didn't respect the condition are left. So in this case, 20.
Thus the final output in this example is: 
(6 15) and (20).

To give you another example if we add 22 and 45 in the example, the output would be:
(6 15) (20 22) and (45).